# addToSet equivalent for arrays that contain subdocuments

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a `userSchema` which contains an id and an array of friends. The array of friends is actually an array of another schema which holds id, gender, and name, thus an array of SubDocuments.

```
var attributesSchema = new Schema({

    id: String,
    gender: String,
    name: String

})

var userSchema = new Schema({

    id: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },

    Friends: [attributes]

});
```

Before, I used to have `Friends` equal an array of `String`. `AddToSet` worked fine in that case as it would not add something into the `Friends` array unless it had a different string value. However, with subdocuments, unfortunately, addToSet cannot determine if something is a duplicate or not.

My attempt at not replicating subDocuments was the following :

```
User.update({
    id: req.body.userId
}, {
    $addToSet: {
        Friends: {
            id: req.body.friendId,
            gender: req.body.gender,
            name: req.body.name
        }
    }
});
```

Obviously, this does not work and I'm looking for a way to add unique subdocuments inside the `Friends` array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$not` and `$elemMatch` to actually update when the element is not matching a subdocument element :

```
User.update({
    "id": req.body.userId,
    "Friends": {
        "$not": {
            "$elemMatch": {
                "id": req.body.friendId
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    $addToSet: {
        Friends: {
            "id": req.body.friendId,
            "gender": req.body.gender,
            "name": req.body.name
        }
    }
});
```

You can add fields to `$elemMatch` if you have other duplicates conditions

Comment: Crazy how flexible mongo is with it's operators. Thank you man !